# Creating and laying out widgets using a for loop in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

So i wanted to create 5 buttons in Qt but instead, create just one button and put it in a for loop so i don't have to create each of the 5 buttons manually. I tried different ways but all proved futile. I'm new to C++ and Qt.

Here are the codes;

show.h

```
#ifndef SHOW_H
#define SHOW_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class Show : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Show(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Show();

private:
    QPushButton *button;

};

#endif // SHOW_H
```

show.cpp

```
#include "show.h"
#include "ui_show.h"

Show::Show(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent) {

    int a = 5;

    button = new QPushButton[a];
    button->setText("Ok");

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout[a];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(button)/4; i++) {
        /*here, i wanted to do something like this;     
        'layout[i].addWidget(button[i]);' but didn't work*/
        layout[i].addWidget(button);
    }
    setLayout(layout);
}

Show::~Show() {

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "show.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Show *dialog = new Show;
    dialog->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

After i run the code, i only see one button. 
Your help is deeply appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `show.cpp` change the lines

```
Show::Show(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent) {

    int a = 5;  

    // You only need one layout for all buttons, not one per button.
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout( this );

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        QPushButton * newButton = new QPushButton( this );
        newButton ->setText( "Ok" );
        layout->addWidget( newButton );
    }
    setLayout(layout);
}

Show::~Show() {

}
```

The layout expects a pointer and you only need one layout instead one per button.

Comment: Thanks for that. i think i'll need that answer in  a project i'm working on but the program still displays one button after that

Comment: I have updated my answer. The problem is that you also have one layout for each button. But one layout is already enough.

Comment: Thank you very much! i think that answers my question.

Comment: But can i ask you another question ?

Comment: Sure you can, but if it's not directly related to the current question, you should open a new question.

Comment: It's kind of related. What i was actually working on was, the user has to select a number from a combo box and based on the number the user selects, the same number of objects are displayed to the user

Comment: Ok! never mind. I've figured it out now. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
QPushButton* pButton = new QPushButton("Ok");
```

This creates a single instance of a [QPushButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html).

You can add the button to a layout with a call to [Layout::addWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#addWidget), which internally calls [addItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#addItem).

As the documentation states for addItem: -

> Note: The ownership of item is transferred to the layout, and it's the layout's responsibility to delete it

So your current code creates a single button and as it gets added to each successive layout, it is removed from the layout in which it was previously added.

You're creating one button and adding the same button 5 times. If you want 5 buttons in 5 layouts using a loop, then you need 5 separate instances of the button: -

```
for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) 
{
    QPushButton* pButton = new QPushButton("Ok"); 
    layout[i].addWidget(pButton);
}
```

Comment: i applied your answer but i still see one button. Could you please be clear ? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time. If so, shouldn't the instance i created for the QVBoxLayout also be in the loop like you did for QPushButton ? because after applying your answer, i still see one button. I think what i need now is  your full version of my code so i run it to see if it will work.